# rviz collision detection (fuerte)

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-fuerte, debian, collision-detection

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to enable collision detection in RVIZ (debian/AMD64).

I built a xacro description of my robot, using basic `collision` tags.

Example:

```
    <link name="${prefix}_AX1" >
 <visual> 
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 ${pi/2}" />
 <geometry>
    <box size="${AX_length}  ${AX_width} ${AX_height}"/>
  </geometry>
  <material name="black">
    <color rgba="0 0 0 1.0"/>
  </material>
</visual>
<collision>
    <geometry>
        <box size="${AX_length}  ${AX_width} ${AX_height}"/> 
    </geometry>
  <inertial>
    <mass value=".055"/>
    <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
  </inertial>
</collision>
    </link>
```

The robot has 2 forelegs in the (x,y) plan, parallel to y. I allow them to rotate about z-axis from -pi/2 to pi/2. I thought that the checkbox `collision-enabled` would prevent them from crossing.

Do I have to use gazebo ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62329/rviz-collision-detection-(fuerte)/) by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz is just a visualizer, showing the state of the system.  It does sound like you want a simulator like [gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/). If you are running on a live system there is also collision detection in the [MoveIt planning software](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/MoveIt!).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabien R](https://answers.ros.org/users/2975/fabien-r/) on 2013-09-28**:
Ok, thanks. I'll chekc if I can use MoveIt.